# Bypassing certificate pinning with integrity checks on Android 7 (Nougat) or newer

Tags: root-access, security, 7.0-nougat, certificates, https

How can I bypass [Certificate Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning), or bypass SSL verification entirely, in an Android app on Android 7 or newer that has a built-in hash 'integrity check' to rule out APK modification?

Here is a rundown of the previous solutions and why they don't work:
 [JustTrustMe](https://github.com/Fuzion24/JustTrustMe) [does not work on Android 7](https://github.com/Fuzion24/JustTrustMe/issues/35), and [Android-SSL-TrustKiller](https://github.com/iSECPartners/Android-SSL-TrustKiller) depends on Cydia Substrate, which [is only supported on versions 2.3 through 4.3](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/). That leaves [SSLUnpinning_Xposed](https://github.com/ac-pm/SSLUnpinning_Xposed), which also [does not work](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=74639278&postcount=15) on Android 7.

I'm seeking any solution that works, which could include an Xposed module or other system modification requiring root. However, making such changes to the APK [like these](https://medium.com/@felipecsl/bypassing-certificate-pinning-on-android-for-fun-and-profit-1b0d14beab2b) wouldn't work because they would trip the hash integrity check.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Arya I ended up bypassing the integrity check by decompiling the app with APKtool, first to Java with dex2jar / jd-gui just to get a big picture view, then once I knew where to look I went back to smali and found the integrity check, it simply took a sha1sum of the signature and sent it to the server. So I modified the in-app sha1 function in smali to just return what the 'correct' signature is every time, and that let me edit the app with something like the medium link.

Comment: it seems like there really is no such thing as a foolproof 'integrity check' on an android app, or at least not one i've seen yet. so it's just a matter of finding it and disabling it from tripping.

Comment: Here, check it out. I still have not tried it https://blog.nviso.be/2017/12/22/intercepting-https-traffic-from-apps-on-android-7-using-magisk-burp/